# Can putAll of guava bloom filter be used to create a new bloom filter of larger size?

Tags: guava, bloom-filter

Google guava has an implementation of the classic bloom filter. Creating one involves specifying number of insertions and false positive probability expected. I want to know whether the [putAll](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html#putAll%28com.google.common.hash.BloomFilter%29) function provided can be used to create a new filter allowing a larger number of insertions than that of the bloom filter argument passed to it while retaining same fpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will not.

As per the javadoc the `putAll` function throws an exception when the filters are not compatible. Two bloom filter are compatible if they have the same number of hash functions; have the same bit size; have the same strategy and; have equal funnels.

The number of hash functions and bitsize are derived from the number of insertions and fpp rate. Creating a new bloom filter with the same fpp and a larger number of insertion will result in different bitsize and number of hash functions.

Comment: Throws IllegalArgumentException - if isCompatible(that) == false, must've  overlooked that